# crontab and deleting older and specific file names

Tags: cron

I have a script that makes files every day like:

```
last-2014-08-01.csv

out-2014-08-01.csv
```

Following this idea:

http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_tips/Unix/UNIX_7.shtml

```
30 12 * * * /u01/app/oracle/bin/rman_backup.pl > /u01/app/oracle/log/rman_backup_$(date +\%Y\%m\%d).log 2>&1
```

I came with this idea for a cron:

```
@daily find /app/calculo/api/last-$(date +\%Y-)*.csv -mtime +30 -delete
@daily find /app/calculo/api/out-$(date +\%Y-)*.csv -mtime +30 -delete
```

What is missing is that is not deleting any file when I test it.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you double check if you quoted the percent sign correctly?

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29578/how-can-i-execute-date-inside-of-a-cron-tab-job

In general I'd suggest you to write a shell script which contains all the logic and just to call it from cron.  You will be free from quoting problems and debugging will also be easier.

```
@daily /path/to/cleanup-csv.bash
```

Be sure to remember to set the `$PATH` environment variable correctly in your shell script.  The crontab sets minimal number of directories to `$PATH`.

Comment: Fast and easy , putting the code in a .sh file solve everything.. thanks @nodakai